# How non-HP PCL print jobs keep PJL-like job control information?

Tags: printing, print-server, accounting

In print queue systems, each job has print job information in print control languages such as Epson EPL or HP PJL; in MS Windows print spools, this information is kept in separate SHD files.

Are there other languages besides EPL, PJL and SHD, holding for example control commands for Adobe Postscript files under Cups?

I want to process such information as number of copies, quality of printing, colour/B&W &c for print accounting, so as to be able to make do without MS Windows as a print server altogether.  Today, my organisation is kept in MS Windows server because such print accounting information is reported by Papercut Print Logger.

Comment: What type of job information are you seeking? Can you frame this in a more answerable manner? E.g. what are you looking to do or accomplish?

Comment: Tried to, is it better?